# SilverStripe admin area overwrite

Tags: silverstripe

In SilverStripe 3.1 is it possible to overwrite the SilverStripe logo and the url (instead of replacing it) which is shown on top of the CMS on the left side?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In SilverStripe 3.1 we can overide the logo by using some custom css.

First we tell `LeftAndMain` to include an extra css file by adding this to our `config.yml`:

```
LeftAndMain:
  extra_requirements_css:
    - mysite/css/leftandmainextracss.css
```

Then in our `leftandmainextracss.css` file we can edit the default logo css to load whatever image we want:

```css
.cms-logo a {
    background: url("../images/new-branding-cms-logo.png") no-repeat left center;
}
```

We can set the url and title in our `config.yml`:

```
LeftAndMain:
  application_link: 'http://www.example.com'
  application_name: 'Example'
  extra_requirements_css:
    - mysite/css/leftandmainextracss.css
```

There are some details on extending the cms interface here: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/customising_the_admin_interface/how_tos/extend_cms_interface/

There is also this module to change the CMS branding. I have not tested this: https://github.com/skorp/Silverstripe--CMSbranding

Comment: The : needs to be removed after the css file name. mysite/css/leftandmainextracss.css

Comment: You are right @GavinBruce. Thank you for pointing out that bug. I have fixed that up now.

Comment: Just to add on to this, you can also set application_link.  He did ask about this as well.

Comment: Thanks @drye I missed that in the question. I have added details on how to change the `application_link` and `application_name` as you have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that I had to make one change to the above solution. When declaring the `extra_requirements_css` in `config.yml` I had to do it this way:

```
LeftAndMain:
  extra_requirements_css: [mysite/css/leftandmainextracss.css]
```

Answer (score 1):

For SilverStripe 4 it has to be with namespaces:

```
SilverStripe\Admin\LeftAndMain:
  extra_requirements_css:
    - mysite/css/leftandmainextracss.css
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that for silverstripe 4.2 the namespace wasn't enough - the directory also needs to be exposed ie. made available at `~/resources/mysite/css/` so i just moved it into my theme.